# Excel write another cell with =IF

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the function `IF` to write in another cell.
I have cell A2, if cell have text "test". I want the cell B2 have text "good" else "bad" BUT the `IF` function MUST be in the cell B3.
So I tried in cell B3:

```
=IF(A2 = "test"; B2 = "good"; B2 = "bad")
```

But nothing happens, cell B2 is normal.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: A formula can **not** alter the value of another cell. Why not put the formula directly in `B2`? >> `=IF(A2="test";"good";"bad")`

Comment: Ok, thx i will find another way! good day

Comment: What's currently in B3 that this formula can't live there? I'm trying to understand, because there might be a solution using VBA, but that's more complicated for something that seems otherwise straightforward